# Where to find purpose of each system default Groups and Users in Linux

Tags: command-line, users, group, man, documentation

when I `cat /etc/group` and `cat /etc/passwd` I get a list in which I find many I don't know. I know only group `sudo` group. But there is are many which I don't knows such as `sys`, `adm` .... I like to learn about them. But I did not find a good article online. Is there any specific documentation or man page to learn about them.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what system you’re using; there are a number of Q&As on the topic, on this site, such as:

- [How to know which users / groups can safely be deleted?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/579326/86440)
- [What Users should be expected in /etc/group adm: group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/682679/86440)
- [Which users are necessary on Unix/Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/484618/86440)
- [What is the Debian counterpart of the admin group, and what group on Debian makes files accessible to only the owner and the administrators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/409102/86440)

and on Retrocomputing.SE: [What was the purpose of those special user accounts in Unix?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/24922/79)

For Debian specifically, the default groups and users are [documented in `users-and-groups.sgml`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/base-passwd/-/blob/master/doc/users-and-groups.sgml) which is shipped as `/usr/share/doc/base-passwd/users-and-groups.txt.gz` on installed systems.